# Android studio pop up window?

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to make a simple popup window to show up when the user taps on the sprite. I've made a layout for the popup, it doesn't show up. Am I missing something?

Edit: here's the rest of my Activity class:

```
public class UniverseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG = UniverseActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private UniverseThread thread;

private Galaxy player;
public Galaxy getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

//components:
private SeekBar speedBar;
private ProgressBar timeBar;
private UniverseView surfaceView;
private ImageView playerSprite;
private ImageView otherSprite;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_universe);

    speedBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    timeBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    surfaceView = (UniverseView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

    playerSprite = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playerGalaxy);
    player = new Galaxy("Milky Way", true, new Velocity(), playerSprite, 1);

    otherSprite = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.otherGalaxy);

    playerSprite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupWindow infoWindow = new PopupWindow(findViewById(R.id.galaxy_info_popup));
            Log.d(TAG, "Player sprite clicked, stopping time and bringing up window...");
            Log.d(TAG, "Will this please work?");
            speedBar.setProgress(0);
            infoWindow.showAtLocation(surfaceView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
            infoWindow.update(50,50,300,500);
        }
    });
}
```

And my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:id="@+id/galaxy_info_popup"
android:background="#ffffff">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/infoPicture"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="infoText"
    android:id="@+id/infoText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/infoPicture"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get `PopUpWindow` working, but I got the same effect much easier with Android's `Dialog` class.

This is what I ended up with:

```
infoPopUp = new Dialog(this);
infoPopUp.setContentView(R.layout.info_popup);
```

In the onClickListener:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Player sprite clicked, stopping time and bringing up window...");
speedBar.setProgress(0);
infoPopUp.setTitle(player.getName());
((ImageView)infoPopUp.findViewById(R.id.infoPicture)).setImageDrawable(player.getSprite().getDrawable());
infoPopUp.findViewById(R.id.option1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
infoPopUp.findViewById(R.id.option2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
infoPopUp.findViewById(R.id.continueButton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
((TextView)infoPopUp.findViewById(R.id.infoText)).setText(player.toString());
infoPopUp.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

The last line should be like -

```
     infoWindow.showAtLocation(surfaceView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
     infoWindow.update(50, 50, 300, 80);
```

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: I put that in, as well as changed surfaceView.findFocus() to just surfaceview. But still, nothing is showing up.

Comment: Better if you share your layout and Activity class, so it will easy to troubleshoot your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the constructor `PopupWindow(View view)` does not set the actual popup window size. It will default to 0 height and 0 width. You will probably have to call `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` after creating your popup or use other constructor. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#PopupWindow(android.view.View)) is the Android documentation on PopupWindows. I would probably use `PopupWindow(View view, int width, int height)`. Another problem might be that the view you are passing in may not be inflated correctly or may be invalid depending on the situation. Another solution would be to call `update()` and specify the size you want.